# compare multiple rows in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am pretty new in excel and need some help.
I have an excel which has 2 Tables (**Table1** and **Table2**).
In **Table1** column **C**, there should be the input.

[image]

```
There are 3 conditions:
1) Table1.OrtNr == "A1"
2) Table1.TagNr == Table2.TagNr
3) If Table2.OD_OU == "OD" then input **OD**, if empty input **OU**
```

This should be the result of **Table1**:

[image]

Comment: Is `=IF(B2="A1",IF(VLOOKUP(A2,$A$8:$C$11,3,FALSE)="OD","OD",IF(VLOOKUP(A2,$A$8:$C$11,3,FALSE)="","OU","")),"")` already enouth?

Answer (score 0):

=IF(B2="A1";IF(VLOOKUP(A2;$A$8:$C$12;3;FALSE)="OD";"OD";"OU");"")